# What does IIS recycling wait for?

Tags: asp.net, iis

What I mean is that IIS recycles app domains, but tries to let pending requests finish [while already starting a new one](https://serverfault.com/a/333948/147633). What if all requests have responded, but there's a Task running, will the app get recycled immediately or will it get the same grace period as when a request hasn't responded yet?

Comment: Overlapping has been the default setting of application pool recycle since IIS 6, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx It would be your responsibility to design the application to work nicely with that, or you have to disable overlapped recycling.

Comment: @LexLi Did you mean to respond to a different question? I don't see how it relates to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't register the `Task` with the web app using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx, then the app will only gracefully "shutdown" its own request threads. If you do add the `Task` to the queue, then it will try and wait for the `Task` to complete. However, the waiting period is not indefinite.

Scott Hanselman has a nice article on running async tasks.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx