# Prevent corruption between new AppDomain start and old one's end

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm writing a web service which has a collection of items. Web requests often add to this collection, which both saves the item to disk, and to an in memory cache. The problem is that a new instance of a web service is created [before the previous one is recycled](https://serverfault.com/a/333948/147633)  so though when the new one starts, it reads the items from disk, an item might be added by the old AppDomain after the first one starts, and that item will not be present in the cache of the new one.

I don't want to do away with the cache and just check the file every time, for performance reasons. So how can I keep the data up to date?

**EDIT**

The proposed duplicate is so different that if someone thinks it's a duplicate, arguing about it won't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does IIS recycling wait for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739293/what-does-iis-recycling-wait-for)